# i18n currency produces many warnings

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I have the following warning in my vue 3 app:

```
[intlify] Not found 'currency' key in 'US' locale messages.
[intlify] Fall back to number format 'currency' key with 'en-US' locale
[intlify] Fall back to number format 'currency' key with 'en' locale.
[intlify] Not found 'currency' key in 'en' locale messages
[intlify] Fall back to number format 'currency' with root locale.
```

This is how I set it up:

```
const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  globalInjection: true,
  numberFormats: config.formats.number,
  dateTimeFormats: config.formats.datetime,
});
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(config.formats.number, undefined, 2)
);
```

The output of console.log is:

```
{
  "DE": {
    "currency": {
      "style": "currency",
      "currency": "EUR",
      "currencyDisplay": "symbol"
    }
  },
  "US": {
    "currency": {
      "style": "currency",
      "currency": "USD"
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I use it in setup (composition api):

```
const { n } = useI18n({
  inheritLocale: true,
  useScope: 'local',
});
const formattedMoney = computed(() => {
  console.log(amount.value, location.value);
  return n(amount.value, 'currency', location.value);
});
```

The output of console.log is:

> 180.62 'US'

In the end it will produce `US$180.62`, is it possible to produce this output without all the warnings?

I would like to access $n in the setup without having to call the useI18n, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with a very similar problem, and setting `useScope: "global"` instead of `useScope: "local"` solved it for me.

I believe the reason for this is that you use `createI18n()` elsewhere, but I am already way out of my depth here.

Following the [docs](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/injection.html#n-value) it is possible to load $n without calling `useI18n()`, using `const $n = app.config.globalProperties.$n` though I am unsure whether this is desirable.